# not able to load javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am using java script after making an ajax call to display the data in a div with new JS content. Please refer to the code below:

//ajax call from a.jsp

```
var goUrl = "/testMethod/getTestMethod;
            var httpRequest=null;
            var refreshContent = "null";
            httpRequest = XMLHTTPObject();
            httpRequest.open("POST", goUrl, true);
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {ajaxFunction(refreshThisDiv,httpRequest); } ;
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            httpRequest.send(null);



function ajaxFunction(refreshThisDiv,httpRequest){

    var serversideValidation = true;
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(httpRequest.status == 200)
        {
            results =  httpRequest.responseText;  // http.responseXML; which will lead to an XML based response, if we were to have some XML output from a server file

            if(results != 'null') {
                var test= document.getElementById(refreshThisdiv);

                test.style.display = '' ;
                test.innerHTML =  results;


            }
```

//Below is in b.jsp which is new content to display.

```
<div id="test">
</div>
<script>
 var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.innerHTML ="HI";
</script>
```

Results are coing fine and redirecting to the b.jsp and displaying the html content. But  tags are not working :(

I want to see Hi after ajax call is completed for that div. Please help me.

Comment: In what way are they "not working"? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: <script> tags are not working because I made n ajax call and displaying the content asynchronously. <script> tags will not work if we call asynchronously. We have to make it synchronize call. (I am not getting any specific error)

Comment: Whatever is there in the script, please add it after `test.innerHTML = results;`

Comment: @Vijay thanks a lot. I got the mistake and your suggestion worked out.

Answer (score 4):

The ID is not `#test`, but `test`. `#test` is a selector that you'd use with jQuery, CSS or `document.querySelector`. `document.getElementById` requires, unsurprisingly, the ID. :)

Comment: Hi @Amadan thanks for the correction. But still after making the ajax call is completed I need the javascript. Even alert is not coming up in the new jsp content

Comment: Sorry, but... there is no Ajax in your posted code. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Hi @Amadan. I have added the code. Please check it out.

Comment: So basically you're adding stuff with `innerHTML` and expecting it to execute scripts in it? This might be a duplicate: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById()` just needs the name of the ID. You incorrectly used CSS-ish syntax by passing `#test` where only `test` is needed.

Corrected new code:

```
<div id="test">
</div>
<script>
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  test.innerHTML ="HI";
</script>
```

Comment: hi @Matt thanks for the correction. But still after making the ajax call is completed I need the javascript. Even alert is not coming up in the new jsp content

Comment: Could possibly update your question and provide a more complete code example? There is no ajax in your original example.

Comment: Hi @Matt. I have added the code . Please check it out.

Comment: Can anyone help me in splitting a javascript list into two different lists?

I have a javascript list. Using a delimeter I want to split that into two lists.Here I am using ':' as a delimeter. saye we have a list a as:

list a = [1,2,3,:,4,5]

Now I want to split that into two different lists as

list b = [1,2,3]
list c =[4,5]

Can anyone Please suggest the optimal solution using javascript / jquery.

Comment: a) `[1,2,3,:,4,5]` is not a valid JavaScript list, so we can't know how to answer this. b) While it is okay to ask for clarifications on the current question, this is completely unrelated: post as a new question.